# Extending Optional<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, swift2, anyobject

I would like to make an extension on Optional<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>. How can I write this?

I was expecting it to be something like

```
extension Optional where 
Wrapped : Dictionary,
Key : String,
Value : AnyObject { ... }
```

but it wants Dictionary to take the parameters directly, and even if this worked I expect it would complain that String was not a protocol. So I try

```
extension Optional where Wrapped : Dictionary<String, AnyObject> { ... }
```

but here it complains that `type 'Wrapped' constrained to non-protocol type 'Dictionary<String, AnyObject>'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use dot syntax to access the Key and Value of Wrapped.

```
extension Optional where Wrapped: DictionaryLiteralConvertible, Wrapped.Key: StringLiteralConvertible, Wrapped.Value: AnyObject {
    func doSomething() {
        print("did it")
    }
}
```

now you can call this:
`Optional(["asdf":123]).doSomething()`

but not this:
`Optional([123:123]).doSomething()`

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning that `let foo = Optional(["asdf":123])` will not have access to `.doSomething`, as `foo` will be of type `Optional<Dictionary<String, Int>>`, and since `Int` is a value type, it does not conform to `AnyObject`. On the other hand, `let foo : [String:AnyObject]? = Optional(["asdf":123])` _will_ have access to `.doSomething()` (and this is the implicit type use in your example above), where the `Value` of this single entry will be of type `__NSCFNumber` (obj-c/foundation _class_ type).

Comment: @dfri you are right, if you import Foundation, otherwise there is no such a bridge (so, that is fine and expected)